# Wagtail, accessing home page in jinja2 templates

Tags: django, jinja2, wagtail

I have two pages extending a base.html.  home_page and  works_page. I am trying to add a favicon image to the base.html. I have decided to  add a favicon field to home_page which is my root page.

```
<link rel='icon' href='/media/{{page.favicon.file}}' />
```

When active page is works_page   the {{page}}  has no favicon field and I get an error. Is there a way to access always the root page from templates?

as {{ root_page }} maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`{{ request.site.root_page }}` is one way of obtaining it. However, I think the root of the problem is that `favicon` shouldn't be a field of the homepage, since it's a property of the site in general, not that specific page. The `wagtail.contrib.settings` module would be a good fit for this: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/contrib/settings.html

Comment: Yes at first I thought of a way to modify settings-sites-site edit page adding a favicon field but I couldn't found a proper way to this. I think the best way would be to modify the added site edit page. Am I missing something in the  doc?