# Reference Wagtail root page in templates

Tags: templates, operators, wagtail, comparison-operators

Currently I display a link to my sites homepage in the base template using this code :

```
{% if page.slug != 'homepage' %}
    <!-- insert link code here -->
{% endif %}
```

However I like to reuse my code and sometimes the page is called something else.  What I would like to write is something like :

```
{% if page != request.site.root_page %}
```

However this does not work, although if I display the values of these fields in the template they are both equal or not as expected ...

```
<p>{{ request.site.root_page }} and {{ page }}<p>
```

Results in :

```
<p>Contact and Contact</p> # On the root page
```

or

```
<p>Contact and Test</p> # On a different page
```

The opposite problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017568/wagtail-accessing-home-page-in-jinja2-templates) as the data is not specific to one page, but to every page except one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Okay in the process of explaining the question, I also found the answer.  It doesn't work (I believe) because although these values look the same, they are actually objects with different properties, therefore the comparison fails.

In order for the comparison to succeed you need to extract values from each object and compare them.  So this will not work ...

```
{% if page != request.site.root_page %}
```

However both of these do work ...

```
{% if page.title != request.site.root_page.title %}
```

... or ...

```
{% if page.url != request.site.root_page.url %}
```

Kicking myself now, but hopefully my public humiliation will help someone in the future.